# SQL MAX on primary key, is filter condition unncessary if it is already indexed?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
select MAX(id) from studenthistory 
where class_id = 1 
   and date(created_at) = '2021-11-05' 
   and time(created_at) > TIME('04:00:00') 
group by student_id

composite indexes = ("class_id", "student_id", "created_at")
```

id is the primary key.

Is `date(created_at) = '2021-11-05' and time(created_at) > TIME('04:00:00')` filter condition unnecessary for Max function since studenthistory is already indexed on class_id and student_id?

The only reason I added that datetime filter is because this table will get huge over time. (historical data) And I wanted to reduce the number of rows the query has to search.

But for the case of Max function - I believe MAX would simply fetch the last value without checking the whole row, if it is indexed.

So can i safely remove the datetime filter and turn it into

```
select MAX(id) from studenthistory 
where class_id = 1 
group by student_id
```

And have the same performance? (or better since it does not need to filter further?)

Checking the query plan seems like the performance is similar, but the size of the table is rather small as of now..

First:

```
| -> Group aggregate: max(id)  (cost=1466.30 rows=7254) (actual time=2.555..5.766 rows=3 loops=1)
    -> Filter: ((cast(studenthistory.created_at as date) = '2021-11-05') and (cast(riderlocation.created_at as time(6)) > <cache>(cast('04:00:00' as time))))  (cost=740.90 rows=7254) (actual time=0.762..5.384 rows=5349 loops=1)
        -> Index lookup on studenthistory using idx_studenthistory_class_id_931474 (class_id=1)  (cost=740.90 rows=7254) (actual time=0.029..3.589 rows=14638 loops=1)
 |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Second:

```
| -> Group aggregate: max(studenthistory.id)  (cost=1475.40 rows=7299) (actual time=0.545..5.271 rows=10 loops=1)
    -> Index lookup on studenthistory using idx_studenthistory_class_id_931474 (class_id=1)  (cost=745.50 rows=7299) (actual time=0.026..4.164 rows=14729 loops=1)
 |
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Many thanks in advance

---

UPDATE: applying @rick james's suggestion:

Changed index to (class_id, student_id, id).

```
FLUSH STATUS;
explain FORMAT=JSON SELECT MAX(`id`) `0` FROM `studenthistory`
    WHERE `class_id`=1 AND `created_at`>='2021-11-05T18:25:50.544850+00:00'
    GROUP BY `student_id`;


| {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "940.10"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "studenthistory",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "fk_studenthist_student_e25b0310",
          "idx_studenthistory_class_id_931474"
        ],
        "key": "idx_studenthistory_class_id_931474",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "class_id"
        ],
        "key_length": "4",
        "ref": [
          "const"
        ],
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 8381,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 2793,
        "filtered": "33.33",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "102.00",
          "eval_cost": "279.34",
          "prefix_cost": "940.10",
          "data_read_per_join": "130K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "created_at",
          "student_id",
          "class_id"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "(`test-table`.`studenthistory`.`created_at` >= TIMESTAMP'2021-11-05 18:25:50.54485')"
      }
    }
  }
} |
```

i.e. only class_id is used as an index, (as created_at is no longer in the index. rows_produced_per_join is lower due to filter: 2793,

Without datetime filter:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
mysql> explain FORMAT=JSON SELECT MAX(`id`) `0` FROM `studenthistory`
    WHERE `class_id`=1  GROUP BY `student_id`;


| {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "854.75"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "studenthistory",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "fk_studenthistory_student_e25b0310",
          "idx_studenthistory_class_id_931474"
        ],
        "key": "idx_studenthistory_class_id_931474",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "class_id"
        ],
        "key_length": "4",
        "ref": [
          "const"
        ],
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 8381,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 8381,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "using_index": true,
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "16.65",
          "eval_cost": "838.10",
          "prefix_cost": "854.75",
          "data_read_per_join": "392K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "student_id",
          "class_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
} |
```

Runs on all 3 indexes ("class_id", "student_id", "id"), same 8381 number of rows slightly lower query cost (940 -> 854)

Applying the first query with original index ("class_id", "student_id", "created_at") yields:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
    explain FORMAT=JSON SELECT MAX(`id`) `0` FROM `studenthistory`
    WHERE `class_id`=1 AND `created_at`>='2021-11-05T18:25:50.544850+00:00'
    GROUP BY `student_id`;

| {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "858.94"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "studenthistory",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "fk_studenthistory_student_e25b0310",
          "idx_studenthistory_class_id_931474"
        ],
        "key": "idx_studenthistory_class_id_931474",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "class_id"
        ],
        "key_length": "4",
        "ref": [
          "const"
        ],
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 8381,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 2793,
        "filtered": "33.33",
        "using_index": true,
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "20.84",
          "eval_cost": "279.34",
          "prefix_cost": "858.94",
          "data_read_per_join": "130K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "created_at",
          "student_id",
          "class_id"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "(`test-table`.`studenthistory`.`created_at` >= TIMESTAMP'2021-11-05 18:25:50.54485')"
      }
    }
  }
} |
```

The cost this time is 858, rows "rows_examined_per_scan": 8381, "rows_produced_per_join": 2793. Only class_id was used as key however. (why.?) not the remaining student_id and created_at

Comment: You are confused. Stop being confused.If the query yields the correct result: it might be correct. Performance is not an issue. Correctness is.

Comment: Why do you have `and time(created_at) > TIME('00:00:00')`? Why are you excluding records that were created exactly at midnight on any date?

Comment: I believe your composite index should allow the query to be done without scanning. Maybe a better one would be `(student_id, class_id, id)`

Comment: What do you mean by "MAX(id) is already indexed on class_id and student_id"?  `MAX(id)` is not a table; it cannot be indexed.  Did you perhaps mean that `studenthistory` is indexed on those columns?

Comment: @Barmar, that time is just an example (as well as the table name and column name.) This query will be run on a table that is inserted by 90k devices (sensor data) every second ~ every 10 seconds depending on the device type.

In real scenario this would be 'the last 12 hours'. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you are right, edited the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query 1**

```
select MAX(id) from studenthistory 
where class_id = 1 
   and date(created_at) = '2021-11-05' 
   and time(created_at) > TIME('04:00:00') 
group by student_id
```

Don't split up the date; change to

```
AND created_at > '2021-11-05 04:00:00'
```

If you want to check rows that were 'created' on the day, use something

```
AND created_at >= '2021-11-05'
AND created_at  < '2021-11-05' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Or, if you want to check for "today":

```
AND created_at >= CURDATE()
```

After 4am this morning:

```
AND created_at >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 4 HOUR
```

Using `date(created_at)` makes the `created_at` part of the `INDEX` unusable.  (cf "sargable")

```
select MAX(id) ... group by student_id
```

Is likely to return multiple rows -- one per student.  Perhaps you want to get rid of the `group by`?  Or specify a particular `student_id`?

**Query 2** *may* run faster:

```
select MAX(id) from studenthistory 
where class_id = 1 
group by student_id
```

But the optimal index is `INDEX(class_id, student_id, id)`,  (It is OK to include both composite indexes.)

It may return multiple rows, so perhaps you want

```
select student_id, MAX(id) from studenthistory 
where class_id = 1 
group by student_id
```

**MAX**

> I believe MAX would simply fetch the last value without checking the whole row, if it is indexed.

Sometimes.

Your second query can do that.  But the first query cannot -- because of the range test (on created_at) being in the way.

**EXPLAIN**

> query plan seems ... similar

Alas, `EXPLAIN` leaves details out.  You can get some more details with `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`, but not necessarily enough details.

I think you will find that the second query will give a much smaller value for "Rows" after adding my suggested index.

A way to get an accurate measure of "rows (table or index) touched":

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

**Sensor data**

For sensor data, consider multiple tables:

- The raw data ("Fact" table, in Data Warehouse terminology).  This has one row per reading per sensor.
- The latest value for each sensor.  This has one row for each of the 90K sensors.  It will be a lot easier to maintain this table than to "find the latest" value for each sensor; that's a "groupwise-maximum" problem.
- Summary data.  An example is to have high/low/average/etc values for each sensor.  This has one row per hour (or day or whatever is useful) per sensor.

Comment: The query only had MAX(ID) because it was a part of a sub query - I tried to only provide the "minimal reproducible example" as stackoverflow guideline suggested but it seemed like it caused more confusion that I'd hoped. I apologise for that.

To provide more context, student_id is actually a sensor device_id and this table is inserted every 1-10 seconds by each sensor. (about 90k devices)

Comment: This would be the full query without the datetime (query 2 as subquery).
i.e. Fetch the latest data for each sensor in a given sensor class (1 in this example),
```
    SELECT *  FROM `studenthistory` WHERE `id` IN      
         (select MAX(id) from studenthistory where class_id = 1 
    group by student_id)
```

Comment: Your answer is great, I learnt a lot - especially the date function not being sargable and the perfomance of query 2 is better than query 1 because first - it is indexed and second, if the index is `INDEX(class_id, student_id, id)`, then MAX(id) would be O(1) operation. Many thanks for your answer. 

That tip on FLUSH STATUS and EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON is great, I will run it now.

Comment: I added query plan in the question. What is wierd is (Explain FORMAT=JSON SELECT MAX(`id`) `0` FROM `studenthistory` WHERE `class_id`=1 AND `created_at`>='2021-11-05T18:25:50.544850+00:00' GROUP BY `student_id`;) This query is only utilising the very first class_id index, not the remaining student_id and created_at index.

Comment: @zcahfg2 - I'm working on a blog on how to work with "sensor data", so I am actually happier to talk about the real problem instead of the "minimal reproducible example".  I added to my Answer.  Notice that I have strayed from your original question -- because it seems that your original question is better answered a different way.

Comment: @zcahfg2 - In your JSON tests, finish off the `WHERE` columns before going to the `GROUP BY`.  Add all the indexes discussed; see which one it picks.

Comment: @zcahfg2 - after pondering my comments on sensors, you might want to start a new Question with sensor queries and not student queries.

Answer (score 1):

The query:

```
select MAX(id) from studenthistory 
where class_id = 1 
group by student_id
```

Can be fast if you create the index:

```
create index ix1 on studenthistory (class_id, student_id, id);
```

Comment: You are right! Amazing. 
Just to check - since there will be a lot of data on this table each day.
I won't need a created_at filer if I use Max(id) like this? 

I don't want the query to scan all records under a particular student (In real like scenario this is a sensor device id) to find the Max id. 

If Max function is O(1) time operation then this would be perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @zcahfg2 If your query ever becomes slow because you are reading a massive number of rows each time, then you can use a filter by date to reduce the number of rows read by the query. The query would then be modified to add this filter, and the index would need to be modified accordingly.